# Is there a Selenium method to verify what it is written in a drop down box?

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried to verify what it is written in a drop down box after the element is moved with drag and drop. I have tried using the `selectByVisibleText()` method but I realized this method is not relevant. Does anybody know if there is a method in Selenium that would fit my description?

Here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class DragAndDrop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://formy-project.herokuapp.com/dragdrop");

        WebElement seleniumLoggo =driver.findElement(By.id("image"));
        WebElement box=driver.findElement(By.id("box"));

        Actions actions=new Actions(driver);
        actions.dragAndDrop(seleniumLoggo,box).build().perform();

       new Select( driver.findElement(By.id("box")).selectByVisibleText());

      // driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Select oSelect = new Select(box); Then oselect.selectByVisibleText() could just use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually trivial (though probably not very intuitive) - just call `getText()` on the element:

```
String theText = driver.findElement(By.id("box")).getText();
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the input. Indeed i have managed to get the desired info.